# Difference and when to use text=true and get_text()

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.6

i am leaning bs4 library if someone can please explain what is Difference and when to use text=true and get_text()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If used with `find_all` or `find`, `text=true` looks for every tags with texts inside it while `get_text()` returns the text from your found tags.